# NodeJS: function name reference error

Tags: javascript, node.js

how is this possible, that `f(false)` thrown reference error about the function name? i.e. `f` is not defined.

```
const f = (startOver) => {
  console.log('startOver', startOver)
  if (startOver) {
    f(false)
  }
}

f(true)
```

Most of the time it works, but suddenly server has crashed with this error. I don't get, how it's even possible?

Comment: The given code does not explain that behaviour, so the error has to be somewhere else. Are you sure the error is reported for one of those lines you show?

Comment: I have tried the same and its working all the time. It should be another code changing the reference of `f`

Comment: What version of nodejs are you using? Are you using trinspilers?

Comment: @t.niese, i'm sure the inners of this function has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Aruna there is only two places where the function is being called: right after the function and within the function. I understand it sounds ridiculous, but i'm surprised as well.

Comment: @PashaRumkin the error occurred with node version 4.2.1

Comment: Make sure you don't use the variable f in another scope (i.e: for another function within the same scope as the one you're using and it's not behaving as it should do).

Comment: The error message of node tells you exactly on which line and in which file the error happens. So which of the statements cases this error based on the error message?

Comment: @t.niese, message pointed to the line within the function itself